# Can't import script from other folder

Tags: python

Anyone knows how to import an entire script from another folder without using *os* ? specifically  I want to import the script `utils_database.py` in `basic_etl.py` I tried to use `from utils import utils_database` in basic_etl.py but it does not work.

Thanks!

Comment: [duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root folder of your project is one level up from the `utils` folder, so you have to include `01.etl` as the top-level package, but then `01.etl` is not a valid package name as it starts with a number, so you should rename the folder to something like `etl` first and then do `from etl.utils import utils_database` in `base_etl.py`.

Comment: This is all assuming that `01.etl` lives in your `PYTHONPATH`. If not, you must add it there first.